# Cypher: Remove Nodes from Path

Tags: path, neo4j, cypher

I want to find a path (in this case the entire database), where there is a `:B` node that has no incoming `:s`-edge and then remove all the `:B`s of the path.

This is my test database:

```
MERGE (B1:B {name:"B1"})-[:t]->(B2:B {name:"B2"})-[:t]->(B3:B {name:"B3"})-[:t]->(B4:B {name:"B4"})-[:t]->(B5:B {name:"B5"})-[:t]->(C1:D {name:"D1"})
MERGE (A1:A {name:"A1"})-[:s]->(B1)
MERGE (A2:A {name:"A2"})-[:s]->(B2)
MERGE (A3:A {name:"A3"})-[:s]->(B4)
MERGE (A5:A {name:"A5"})-[:s]->(B5)
```

5)

[image]

The query I tried last is this, but it throws an error:

```
MATCH p=(n:A)-[*] ->(o:B)-[:t*]->(m:D)  
WITH NODES(p)[1..-1] AS Pspace_nodes, o, p
MATCH o WHERE NOT ()-[:s]->(o)
FOREACH (n IN Pspace_nodes| MATCH n-[*]-() DELETE n , r)
```

Error message:

```
py2neo.cypher.error.statement.InvalidSyntax: Invalid use of MATCH inside FOREACH (line 4, column 29 (offset: 143))
"FOREACH (n IN Pspace_nodes| MATCH n-[*]-() DELETE n , r)
```

How do I express this in a valid fashion?

Comment: Your error message and your query show a different `FOREACH` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

This might work for you:

```
MATCH p=(:A)-[r*]-(:D)
WHERE ANY (x IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE x:B AND NOT ()-[:s]->(x))
WITH REDUCE(s =[], y IN NODES(p)[1..-1]| CASE WHEN y:B THEN s + y ELSE s END ) AS todo
UNWIND todo AS node
WITH DISTINCT node
DETACH DELETE node;
```

In a larger DB, this can take a long time to run because the `MATCH` specifies a variable-length path. If this is a problem, you should use a reasonable upper bound (e.g., `[r*..5]`).

The `WHERE` clause filters for paths with a `B` node with no incoming `:s` relationship. The `REDUCE` function collects all the `B` nodes in the path. The `UNWIND` puts each `B` node in a separate row. The `DISTINCT` removes all duplicate nodes so that the deletion attempt will not try to delete a node twice (which causes neo4j to generate an error). The `DETACH DELETE` clause will not only delete those `B` nodes but also all their relationships (since you are not allowed to delete a node without also doing that).

Comment: I am getting "(no changes, no rows)".

Comment: That works. But in other cases the `CASE` keyword does need the variable or property in question after it before the cases are listed. why not here?

Comment: The [CASE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-expressions.html#query-syntax-case) expression supports two syntaxes.

Comment: I have yet again modified my answer to prevent attempt to delete the same node twice, which is problematical for neo4j.